# how to rewrite url with the htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have successfully rewritten the first part of my URL. So, now instead of saying mysite/new_sect.php it says mysite.com/new

This is the code I used:

```
RewriteRule  ^new/?$  new_sect.php  [NC,L]
```

Now, I have this other URL that I am trying to rewrite, but it is not working and I get a 404 page.

This is the url: `new_sect.php?pageName=about`

This is what I want to name it: new/about

```
RewriteRule    ^new/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    new_sect.php?pageName=$1    [NC,L]
```

Then I also have this url that I want to rewrite, but like above I get the same error, which is also a 404.

This is the url: `new_sect.php?pageName=about&showSubCategory=media`

This is what I want to name it: new/about/media

```
RewriteRule    ^new/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    new_sect.php?pageName=$1&showSubCategory=$2     [NC,L]
```

I have tried changing my code, but it doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For the first URL, you need to use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^new/([^/]*)$ /new_sect.php?pageName=$1 [L]
```

Leaving you with: `www.example.com/new/about`

For your second URL, you need to use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^new/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /new_sect.php?pageName=$1&showSubCategory=$2 [L]
```

Leaving you with: `www.example.com/new/about/media`

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.